# enumerate(list) removes items from a list and convert it to string/int

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, enumerate

This question is just out of curiosity. Suppose I have the list `x`

```
   x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

When I enumerate through this list and make an intended mistake as follow:

```
  for i, x in enumerate(x):
      print i + " : " + x 
      #Should use str(i) and str(x)
```

predictably this error is produced:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#26>", line 2, in <module>
        print i + " : " + x
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

However `x` list is converted to one letter string `'a'`.

```
  print x
  'a'
```

I tried the same with numerical list `x = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `x` was converted to and integer of `1`.

Why did this happen? and why it did not happen when I use str(i) and str(x)?

Comment: Because strings cannot be added into integers.

Comment: The integer is the counter, `i`, and the string is `':'` in the error message. `x` is a string in both cases. Nothing was ever removed from the list. As soon as you try to add `i` to `':'` it's already failing, so it's not going to then attempt to add `x` on top of that.

Comment: This isn't reproducable.

Comment: Hold on, your list is called `x` and you're also assigning values in the list to the name `x`. That is a conflict of names. As soon as you run your loop, you re-bind the name `x` to the first item in the list.

Comment: @roganjosh: Note: It will "work", in the sense that the loop will run to completion, because the old value of `x` is effectively cached as part of `for` loop setup. That said, yes, any reference to `x` after the loop has begun will no longer refer to the original iterable, so while it "works", it's almost certainly going to be confusing/error-prone.

Comment: roganjosh has explained your error due to re-using the name `x`,  But anyway, it's more efficient to let `print` handle the conversion to string and the concatenation, eg `print i, ':', y`

Comment: I am really embarrassed guys from this silly mistake. The x shouldn't be the proper assigning value in this case as it conflicts with the list name x. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with `enumerate` here is a distraction. The real issue is that you have a list called `x` and then you assign the values *within* the list to the name `x` in your `for` loop.

The code doesn't actually crash until you get to:

```
print i + " : " + x
```

Well, by then, the re-binding of the name has already occurred on the previous line:

```
for i, x in enumerate(x):
```

Now `x` points to a different object - the first item in your list, regardless of whether that's a string or an integer. Rename either your list or the loop variable.